# Creating an instance of object using "new" operator works, but using Object.create() does not produce the same results

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

A bit of a JavaScript newbie here. I have the following 2 JavaScript code snippets here which does not do what I am expecting. The examples create an instance of the object "Person" in Example #1 using the "new" operator, and creates a prototype of "Person" in Example #2 using the ES5 Object.create() property.

```
let Person = function(name, age, city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age; 
    this.city = city
}

// Using 'new' operator (working)
let person1 = new Person("Jack Rabit", 40, "Seattle");
Object.values(person1); // Shows "Jack Rabit", 40, "Seattle"
```

But, doing the following using the Object.create() property...does not show the first value of the Property  (in this case "name"):

```
let person2 = Object.create(Person);
person2.name = "Will"; 
person2.age=41; 
person2.city="San Jose";

Object.values(person2); // Shows 41, "San Jose" (Does NOT show the value of the "name" property)
```

What is that I am missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding those as properties to the ```b``` object? Where was b defined?

Comment: Seems like you want to add it to the ```person2``` object.

Comment: Just corrected the variable assignments. Sorry!

Comment: It's probably because functions such as `Person` have a `name` property which is not enumerable, and therefore doesn't show up in `Object.values`. I'm not quite sure what happens when you assign the property on an object that inherits from it, though - or even what you're trying to do by using `Object.create` with a function object.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There seems to be a conflict with the property "name". Any other property name seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So usually when I use `Object.create()` I pass an object to be used at the prototype.  You are currently passing a function as an argument.  This way works

```js
const Person = function(name, age, city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age; 
    this.city = city
}

const person2 = Object.create(new Person());
person2.name = "Will"; 
person2.age=41; 
person2.city="San Jose";

Object.values(person2);
```

It probably has something to do with the fact that functions have their own `name` property for the function itself? But I'm not too sure

Edited:

Confirmed it is just because of the name property, changed name to title to avoid confusion:

```js
const Person = function(title, age, city) {
    this.title = title;
    this.age = age; 
    this.city = city
}

const person2 = Object.create(Person);
person2.title = "Will"; 
person2.age=41; 
person2.city="San Jose";

Object.values(person2);
// ["Will", 41, "San Jose"]
```

Comment: Better to use `Person.prototype` rather than `new Person()`.

Comment: Agreed.  Using Object.create() is outdated as well. Just stick to using the syntatic sugar that comes with classes and the new keyword.

Comment: Yes, there seems to a conflict between the property "name"....

Comment: I've had some trouble with using name in the past as well. Many people don't know but the window object has a name property that has an empty string for the value.  Open up your console and just type ```window.name```.  Lead to a weird bug for me once.

Comment: @UzairAshraf `outdated` is a strong claim there.  I don't know if I'd agree that class syntax is meant to replace classical JavaScript prototypal syntax.  There seems to be a pretty large amount of people that seem to hate the new class syntax and see it as backwards and for people whose backgrounds are not "real" JavaScript programmers.

Comment: @user120242 You're right, my bad.  I didn't mean outdated, I just meant like older?

Comment: @UzairAshraf `window.name` has nothing to do with this though

Answer (score 1):

`Object.create` creates a new object with the given object as its `[[prototype]]`.

You are trying to inherit the properties wrongly here. You are creating the `person2` object with the constructor function `Person` as its prototype. All functions have a non-enumerable and non-writable property called `name`. You can see that by

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Person, "name")
```

The line `person2.name = "Will";` is effectively trying to overwrite this property and does nothing. Also `person2` has effectively become a function.

Here the correct usage would be

```
let person2 = Object.create(new Person());
```

Comment: Not sure if that is correct. Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: "*Also `person2` has effectively become a function.*" - not quite, it might be `instanceof Function`, but it's not callable (`person2()`).

Answer (score 0):

Object.create needs an object to create another object. So use the Person function to return an object. It should look like this:

```
 let Person = function(name, age, city) {
  return {
    name,
    age,
    city
  };
}

// Using 'new' operator (working)
let person1 = new Person("Jack Rabit", 40, "Seattle");

let person2 = Object.create(Person());
person2.name = "Will"; 
person2.age=41; 
person2.city="San Jose";
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.create needs an object to create another object, as a result since `Person` while being a function(a function constructor to be exact) is also an object in javaScript. Therefore Object.create will not complain, but what is happening under the hood when its done this way:

```
let person2 = Object.create(Person);
```

`person2` ends up being assigned some of the properties of a function named 'Person' (which in itself is not a function, it can t be called)
this can be seen here:

```
// person2.name = 'Person'

// person2() Uncaught TypeError: person2 is not a function at <anonymous>:1:1
```

As one of the inherited properties of a Function, its name is read-only, therefore `person2.name = 'some name'` will have no effect. [Function.name MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

The `new` operator will call the constructor which will return an object while inheriting the prototype of the constructor function